# Show a collection in a oneToMany relation in Jhipster

Tags: java, html, angular, spring, jhipster

I have used jHipster to create my app. I have two entities (Course and Subject) with a oneToMany relation, in the view of 'Course' I want to show the subjects. 
I have tried without success this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let subject of course.subjects">
```

The only way I have found is recover all subjects and compare if subject.course.id == course.id but this is not very functional and there must be another way

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let subject of subjects">
<tr *ngIf="subject.course.id == course.id" >
```

**EDIT**

Add the models

course.model.ts

```
export class Course implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public name?: string,
        public subjects?: BaseEntity[],
    ) {
   }
}
```

subject.model.ts

```
export class Subject implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public name?: string,
        public course?: BaseEntity,
    ) {
    }
 }
```

Comment: please make your question more clearer , posting a sampe data of  `subjects` will also help the question

Comment: Sorry, I think the question was well.What don't you understand?

Comment: are you using MapStruct? if you are, check that the subjects are not ignored in the mapper class

Comment: No, i dont use MapStruct

Comment: I understand that you want to retrieve the Course entity with the list of Courses already populated? try using debug mode to check how the Resource is managing the query

Comment: I have a list of Subjects for Course and i want show this subjects in a table in the detail of each course. The query works fine, the problem is in HTML code when i use "let subject of course.subjects"

Comment: so the backend is retrieving a course with the list of subjects already populated, right? then `let subject of course.subjects` should suffice. Make sure you have a non-empty list of subjects

Comment: can you update your post with the ts function that calls the service?

Comment: I already managed to solve it, I have answered the question. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solve the problem. jHipster includes `@JsonIgnore` annotation, so when Json sends the data of the `course`, that no includes the `subjects`. 
I remove that annotation and add this:

> Course.java:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("course")
private Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<>();
```

> Subject.java:

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("subjects")
private Course course;
```